# Tuning Android Applications Version 0.1

Tags: commonsware

I read that "Tuning Android Applications Version 0.1 is now available for subscribers."  I am a subscriber but I don't see the link when I login.  I tried refreshing, but nothing new shows up.  I hope this is the correct place for this question.

Ron

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest if you contact the Commonsware people. I wont post their email address here but if you login and then click on the FAQ tab there is a "let us know" link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

For technical questions about samples, this is a fine place; for operational questions like this, not really. Contact wares -at- commonsware.com and supply your Warescription user ID for assistance.